# Slide elements in from left and right at the same time when a buttons clicked?

Tags: jquery, slide

I'm trying to have two elements slide in on a single click. I'd like the first element (an `img`) to slide in from the left and the other element (a `p` tag) to slide in from the right on click of a button (an `li`). Then, when another button is clicked, I'd like the first two elements to fade away and the next two elements (corresponding to the button clicked) slide in.

Is there a way to loop through these so they are always sliding in.

$('#nav-button-1').click(function() {

```
   $('#people-2').hide();
   $('#people-3').hide();
   $('#people-1').show();

$('.slideleft').animate({
    marginLeft: '103px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
$('#slideright').animate({
    marginRight: '12px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

});

Comment: Show us the code that you have so far

Comment: $('#nav-button-1').click(function() { 
    $('#people-2').hide();
    $('#people-3').hide();
    $('#people-1').show();
    $('.slideleft').animate({ marginLeft: '103px' }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('#slideright').animate({ marginRight: '12px' }, 1000, function() { </br>
        // Animation complete.</br>
    });</br>
}); </br>
I want to be able to loop these 3 divs so that they are always </br>fading out and sliding in. so far it works but after its first</br> click its just hides the div then shows the new one which has been clicked</br>

Comment: @Digby ...maybe you should edit it into your post with proper formatting?

Comment: Sorry first time using this, thought that it was formatted?

Comment: @Digby To edit your post with the proper format: Click the edit link under your post, paste in the code that you put in your comment and and any other code you might have, then format it using the tools above the editor box. The icon that looks like curly braces is the one that puts it in a code sample block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to get started.

I made a function out of your original JS

```
function doAnimation(id) {
    $(id).children('.slideleft').fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: '103px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
    $(id).children('.slideright').fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            marginRight: '12px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
}
```

Here is a method that is called on the button presses. It takes in the ID of the wrapper where the animated items are contained and eventually calls the above method.

```
function animatePeople(id) {
    // If there are visible people
    if ($('.people:visible').length > 0) {
        // Fade out the visible people and then process the following callback function
        $('.people:visible').fadeOut(function () {
            // Reset the margins
            $('.people').css({
                'margin-left': '',
                'margin-right': ''
            });
            // Do the new animation
            doAnimation(id);
        });
    } else {
        // Do the new animation
        doAnimation(id);
    }
}
```

Lastly, these are the handlers for the buttons.

```
$('#nav-button-1').click(function () {
    animatePeople('#people-holder-1');
});
$('#nav-button-2').click(function () {
    animatePeople('#people-holder-2');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQTYc/2/)

Comment: Works Perfectly, Thank you very much for putting up with both my really bad communication and for the help with the script. Cheers!!!!